# How to send data to a users socket id after they have refreshed - socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

To give an example, let's say a user sends some json to a server containing his socket id, and the server takes 5 seconds to respond. When it's ready to respond, it extracts the socket.id from the json object, and emits some data only to that socket.

If the user where to refresh (therefore changing the socket he is connecting via ) between sending the message and the server responding, how would I go about ensuring they still receives the data?

Server:

```js
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("data", function(data) {
    var id = data.socket_id; 
    
    io.sockets.connected[id].emit("response", "sup"); 

    // I know I could just do -> socket.emit("response", "sup") <- but im simply trying it out for      learning purposes
  })
})
```

Client:

```js
socket.emit("data", {
  username: "chris", 
  socket_id: socket.id, 
});

socket.on("response", function(res) {
  console.log(res); 
})
```

Answer (score 8):

If the user refreshes their page, that will make a new socket.io connection that will have a new and different `socket.id`.  So, if you want to be able to identify a particular browser session across refreshes, then you need an identifier that survives a page refresh.  That is not the `socket.id`.

Most likely, you would use some sort of long lasting userID in a cookie.  If you don't already have any sort of authentication happening that gives you a userID in a cookie, then you can simply coin a unique ID in a cookie if there isn't already one anytime a user makes a request to your server.  That will give you a unique userID in a cookie for every incoming socket.io connection (as long as cookies aren't disabled).  When your socket.io connection connects, you can add it to a `Map` object you keep where the userID is the key and the current `socket.id` is the data and you can add the userID as a property on the socket.  When the socket disconnects, you would then remove it from the `Map` object.

Then, when you want to save a reference to the user, you save the userID, not the `socket.id` and that reference stays the same across a page refresh.   When you want to send to the userID, you can look it up in the `Map` object to get the current `socket.id` (which will be automatically kept current by your connect and disconnect event handlers as described above) and then use that to send to it.

Comment: Wont this mean that messages sent within the time of disconnection and reconnection be gone?

Comment: @ChidozieDuru - Yes, you should not be sending messages to a connection that is about to get killed.  The web page containing that connection will be destroyed anyway.  So, even if the data does get through the whole web page will be thrown away on a refresh anyway.

Comment: @ChidozieDuru - Also, you get disconnect messages.  So, the server should be able to know that the socket is now disconnected and is not available to send data on.  You cannot know that the client is about to disconnect.  So, data you send right before the client disconnects can indeed get lost (this is true of any TCP socket).  Clients can disappear at any point in time.  If you must know at the application level whether the client actually received your data or not, then you would likely use client confirmation at the application level.

Comment: please can i have a method to  contact you. I will really appreciate.

Comment: ?? please can you give me a way to reach you effectively.

Comment: @ChidozieDuru - That is not how this place works.  I don't give out my private contact information.  I offer to help people within the context of stackoverflow questions.

Comment: ok thanks. i had a project for you though.